# How to Retrieve an Element in Express.js by Passing a Token Generated by Laravel 8?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, laravel, express

I'm working on two projects simultaneously: one in Laravel 8 and the other in Express.js. In the Laravel project, I generate a token and want to use it to retrieve an element in my Express.js application. How can I pass this token securely from Laravel to Express.js and then use it to fetch the corresponding element?

Here's what I have in mind:

1. I generate a token in Laravel.
2. I send this token to my Express.js application.
3. In Express.js, I create a route to receive the token and use it to fetch the corresponding element.

Could someone guide me on how to implement this securely and efficiently in both Laravel and Express.js?

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show some code on how you are generating the token in laravel and how you validating in express.js?

Answer (score 0):

You can send the token as part of the request body, headers, or query parameters using an HTTPS request.

```
const express = require('express');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const app = express();
const jwtSecret = process.env.JWT_SECRET;

app.post('/fetchElement', (req, res) => {
    const token = req.body.token; // Assuming token is sent in the request body

    jwt.verify(token, jwtSecret, (err, decoded) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Unauthorized' });
        }
        
        const userId = decoded.user_id; // Extract user_id from decoded token
        // Fetch the corresponding element using the user_id
        // Example: Element.findOne({ userId: userId }, (err, element) => { ... });
        
        // Respond with the fetched element
        res.json({ element: fetchedElement });
    });
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Express server running'));
```

Ensure that both Laravel and Express.js applications have the same JWT secret to encode and decode tokens correctly.

Comment: I tried this but in laravel project I'm using Passport so I get this message "invalid algorithm"